# 3 way circle query wins and losses query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given this table

record

```
win loss  rid
1   2     1
2   3     2
3   1     3
```

rid is auto increment unique id. The values in win / loss are unique player ids like 1,2,3 where 1,2,3 refers to a unique player

1 beats 2. 2 beats 3. 3 beats 1. I want the count of how many of these are in the record table.

That is, A won against B, B won against C, C won against A, at least once.

I tried below but it outputs count as 3 when I need the count to be 1

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM record r1, record r2, record r3
WHERE r1.win = r2.loss 
AND r2.win = r3.loss
AND r3.win = r1.loss;


-----
count
3
```

Not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your current logic for finding a 3-way cycle is correct.  The only problem is that your logic is picking up a given 3-way cycle with each of the 3 players as being a starting point.  That is, you are over-counting each cycle 2 times.  So, you may simply divide your count by 3 to get the correct number of cycles:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / 3 AS cnt
FROM record r1
INNER JOIN record r2 ON r1.win = r2.loss
INNER JOIN record r3 ON r2.win = r3.loss AND r3.win = r1.loss
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim's reasoning is correct.  However, I wouldn't overcount and divide.  Instead, I would just look for the cycle that is ordered by the ids:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM record r1 JOIN
     record r2
     ON r1.win = r2.loss
     record r3
     ON r2.win = r3.loss AND
        r3.win = r1.loss
WHERE r1.win < r1.loss AND
      r2.win < r2.loss;
```